# Make KML LineString follow roads

Tags: kml

I am working on a KML file with two co ordinates that I use to draw line strings. It works fine when the roads are straight, but whenever the road curves the lines do not curve. Here is the KML code I use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <Document>
    <open>1</open>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin_hl">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ffff5500</color>
        <scale>0.583333</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>00ffffff</color>
      </LabelStyle>
      <ListStyle />
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <width>3.6</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <fill>0</fill>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="m_pushpin">
      <Pair>
        <key>normal</key>
        <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
      <Pair>
        <key>highlight</key>
        <styleUrl>#s_ylw-pushpin_hl</styleUrl>
      </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Style id="s_ylw-pushpin">
      <IconStyle>
        <color>ffff5500</color>
        <scale>0.5</scale>
        <Icon>
          <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href>
        </Icon>
      </IconStyle>
      <LabelStyle>
        <color>00ffffff</color>
      </LabelStyle>
      <ListStyle />
      <LineStyle>
        <color>ff0000ff</color>
        <width>3.6</width>
      </LineStyle>
      <PolyStyle>
        <fill>0</fill>
      </PolyStyle>
    </Style>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Test Fac 10-26-2020</name>
      <description>Sidewalk</description>
      <sidewalk_missing>No</sidewalk_missing>
      <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>-104.818968772888,39.710975093838,0 -104.810267686844,39.708465999778,0</coordinates>
      </LineString>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>ffff0000</color>
          <width>5</width>
        </LineStyle>
      </Style>
    </Placemark>
    <Placemark>
      <name>Test Fac 10-26-2020</name>
      <description>Sidewalk 1</description>
      <sidewalk_missing>No</sidewalk_missing>
      <LineString>
        <extrude>1</extrude>
        <tessellate>1</tessellate>
        <coordinates>-104.819033145905,39.707747919881,0 -104.814473390579,39.70400883137,0</coordinates>
      </LineString>
      <Style>
        <LineStyle>
          <color>ffff0000</color>
          <width>5</width>
        </LineStyle>
      </Style>
    </Placemark>
  </Document>
</kml>
```

[image: LineStrings screenshot]

I would like the LineString to follow similar to the yellow lines on the road. I looked into Directions API, but can't figure out a better way.

Comment: You need a source of all of the roads coordinates (not just the start and end points).  OpenStreetMaps might have that data.   Google Maps has that data, but check the Terms of Use, storing coordinates from their APIs is not allowed (and can't be displayed on non-Google Maps) or at least wasn't last I checked.

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap

Comment: Thank you, is there an example that shows me how to achieve this? using  OpenStreetMaps or Google Roads or Directions API..thank you

Comment: Are you going to be displaying these KML files on Google Maps, OpenStreetMaps, or something else?

Comment: Google earth, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to query Google Roads API as below and parse the json response and add multi geometry to KML file with the resulting co-ordinates

```
        string url = @"https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/snapToRoads?path=" + beginLat + "," + beginLon + "|" + endLat + "," + endLon + "&interpolate=true&key=";
        System.Net.WebRequest request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
        System.Net.WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        System.IO.Stream data = response.GetResponseStream();
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(data);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        response.Close();
```

Here is the json parser code. The co-ordinates are inside the "locations" table inside the dataset.

```
            jsonString = $"{{ \"snappedPoints\": {{{jsonString.Trim().TrimStart('{').TrimEnd('}')}}} }}";
            var xd = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(jsonString);
            var result = new DataSet();
            result.ReadXml(new XmlNodeReader(xd), mode);
            return result;
```

Thank you all for the help and pointing me towards the right direction.